# Phonegap Android Remote Notification API

Tags: android, api, cordova, push-notification

I was searching for an API like [EasyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) for Android. EasyAPNS allows to add PUSH Notifications in iOS with minimum codeing required and all tested stuff to reduce development time. I was interested to find similar thing for Android too so I may not need to write the whole backend and service stuff for Android. Have you come across any API so far?

I know how notifications in Android works and how can a service be used to generate notifications. The service in Android must listen for remote requests and as they may arrive, it will add to the notification tray.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Minimoesfuerzo did a plugin that integrates UrbanAirship and PhoneGap Android. That may provide you the functionality you need:

http://minimoesfuerzo.org/2011/06/3/urban-airship-integration-android-phonegap-app/